# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess: Subdomain to static link

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to rewrite from

subdomain.domain.com

to an static link like

www.domain.com/pageId5.

The Domains are the same, i tried a lot of things in .htaccess but nothing works. I also found nothing helpfull with the search function, please help!

And Iam working with Drupal, so there are no directories I can point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/pageId5 [R=301,L]
```